# Changing the size of the heatmap specifically in a seaborn clustermap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm making a clustered heatmap in seaborn as follows

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(2)
data = np.random.randn(100, 10)
sns.clustermap(data)
```

but the rows are squished:

[image]

but if I pass a size to the clustermap function then it looks terrible

[image]

is there a way to only increase the size of the heatmap part? So that the row names can be read, but not stretch out the cluster portions.

Comment: No easy way, but you can always manipulate the matplotlib objects after you plot to put them how you want them.

Comment: What should I manipulate? I know that I can access the underlying heatmap axes using the ax_heatmap parameter, but I don't what the name of the matplotlib attribute is that I should be changing. My Google-fu is failing me too.

Comment: I think you'll want to try playing with the `ax_heatmap.set_position` method. You'll need to change the dendrogram axes, too, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @mwaskom commented, I was able to use `ax_heatmap.set_position` along with the `get_position` function to achieve the correct result.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
data = np.random.randn(100, 10)
cm = sns.clustermap(data)
hm = cm.ax_heatmap.get_position()
plt.setp(cm.ax_heatmap.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), fontsize=6)
cm.ax_heatmap.set_position([hm.x0, hm.y0, hm.width*0.25, hm.height])
col = cm.ax_col_dendrogram.get_position()
cm.ax_col_dendrogram.set_position([col.x0, col.y0, col.width*0.25, col.height*0.5])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by passing the value of the dendrogram ratio in the kw arguments

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(2)
data = np.random.randn(100, 10)
sns.clustermap(data,figsize=(12,30),dendrogram_ratio=0.02,cmap='RdBu')
```